# SQLHelper Class

Tags: .net, sqlhelper

Is there a recent version of the SQLHelper class out there. I've been using one for a few years now and was wondering if there is a new version out there for .NET Framework 2.0 or 3.0. I prefer this on small projects vs Microsoft Data App Block (which I use on larger projects).

I came across this link

> http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=f63d1f0a-9877-4a7b-88ec-0426b48df275&displaylang=en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/fd9229c0-53d0-4b3b-a7da-5df4047343a3)...

> SqlHelper was actually replaced with
>   an abstract class, called Database,
>   and two concrete classes that derive
>   from it:  SqlDatabase and
>   OracleDatabase.

Comment: @waqasahmed, I'd be grateful if you share the way you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on this question since it hasen't been answered:

Is there a new version to the 2004 sqlHelper class which can be retrived from:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=f63d1f0a-9877-4a7b-88ec-0426b48df275&displaylang=en

I know there are Application Blocks part of Enterprise Library 4.1 Oct 2008, but I can't find the sqlHelper class in it.

Answer (score 0):

I have an extend version of this library It's available on [GitHub](https://github.com/jeroenpot/SqlHelper): and [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MsSqlHelper/). It was based on the source code of the SqlHelper.

Extra features that i think that aren't in the original

- Async/await
- MySql Support
- Generics