# Timeout issue when using sql helper(Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, timeout, sqlhelper

I am having timeout issues when dealing with long sql queries, the Dataset which timesout for long queries is :

```
static public DataSet Getxxxx(Guid xxxx)
{
    DataSet ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(ConnectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetAllxx", new SqlParameter("@productxx", productxx));

    return ds;
}
```

Where can i set timeout , I am using Microsoft application block version 2.0.

Answer (score 3):

The Data Access Application Block `SqlHelper` has been [phased out in favour of 'Database'](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/fd9229c0-53d0-4b3b-a7da-5df4047343a3/), so you'll need to explicitly create a `DbCommand` and pass it through to `Database.ExecuteDataSet`. You can then set the [`CommandTimeout` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx), to override the default of 30 seconds. e.g. this sets the timeout to 200 seconds:

```
using (DbCommand command = this.Database.GetStoredProcCommand("GetAllxx"))
{
    Database.AddInParameter(command, "@productxx", DbType.Int32, productxx);
    command.CommandTimeout = 200;
    return Database.ExecuteDataSet(command);
}
```