# Calling a stored procedure using vbscript

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, asp-classic, vbscript

I am looking over some code that another programmer made where he calls a stored procedure. Before calling it, he creates an Array with the parameters needed for the stored procedure to query the table. He creates the array like this:

```
param = Array("@Name", 3, 8, "Tom", _
            "@Age", 3, 8, 28, _
            "@City", 100, 200, "Toronto)
```

The stored procedure uses @Name, @Age and @City to query the table.

My question is, what are the numbers in between for?

Comment: Since there are no code comments (or docs)... can you just ask the other developer?

Comment: vbscript is for classic asp. asp.net, as the question is tagged, uses vb.net. Which is right, here? Did you mean to tag your question 'asp-classic' instead of asp.net, did you mean to tag your question 'vb.net' instead of vbscript, or is this a client-side script that only works in internet explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like:

@Name = parameter name

3 = adInteger

8 = length

"Tom" = value

@Age= parameter name

3 = adInteger

8 = length

28 = value

@City= parameter name

100 = length

200 = adVarChar

"Toronto = value

Here is a list for the other ADO Data Types -

http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_datatypes.asp

Comment: Does that mean "Tom" is an integer? If this is asp classic then you're definitely closer to the answer than I am, but it also looks like the 100 and 200 values are in the wrong order. A good puzzle for a Friday afternoon!

Answer (score 0):

Without comments it's impossible to know for sure or without stepping through the code.

Otherwise, if this is asp.net the best you can do is look at the `SqlParameter` class and see the properties it has available:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx

I think you have two strong candidates for `ParameterName` and `Value`, but the two numerical values could be a few different things. `3` just happens to be the numerical value for `SqlDbType.Char` and while `100` has no corresponding `SqlDbType`, the default for that type is `NVarChar.`

The next number could be precision. Take a look at the Database table and see if you can match those values to the fields. For example, is City `VarChar(200)`?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that he is using an array of params, just something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10142254/2385, where I use an array of params to pass to a function who add the params to the ADO command.